# Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'node' as it is null

Tags: node.js, npm, aurelia

when I want to install dependencies of the aurelia project, got this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /Users/ehsanghaffarii/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.1/bin/node /Users/ehsanghaffarii/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --cache=/Users/ehsanghaffarii/.npm/_cacache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit
npm ERR! npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! npm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'node' as it is null.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /Users/ehsanghaffarii/.npm/_cacache/_logs/2021-01-14T17_17_22_767Z-debug.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ehsanghaffarii/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T17_19_13_263Z-debug.log
```

How can fix this?

Node v15.5.1

npm v7.3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to me and [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1832) that you are trying to install global dependencies which require elevated permissions and/or npm package version is bugged. Make sure you have sufficient rights to downgrade `npm` to the earliest version.

Please let me know, if that solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your guide

Comment: for me the only solution that worked is to go back to npm v6 `npm i -g npm@6`

Comment: I got the same error when I deleted my package lock and changed my node dependencies manually. I had to delete my node_modules manaully before I could npm install the changes.

Comment: you could simply run `yarn remove <dependencyName>` instead of manually editing package.json

Answer (score 3):

I had same error and I added

> --force

To the end of the command. works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I got this error on the `npm install`

It resolved by running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Check the node version and npm version before running the above command

if required you can run this too `"echo legacy-peer-deps=true" >> .npmrc`

Answer (score 1):

you can use " yarn install" and "yarn dev"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `yarn add`

- node v14.20.0
- npm v9.1.2
- yarn v3.0.1